# Lower bound for non-negative definite matrix

Tags: self-learning, matrices

I wonder if the following inequality is true, which I can not prove:
$$
e^T A^{-1} \mathrm{diag}(A) \geq 1
$$
where $A$ is non-negative definite matrix,
$\mathrm{diag}(A)$ is the vector of diagonal elements of $A$,
and $e$ is vector of ones.

Thank you!

Comment: This seems better suited to math.SE than here. Is there something especially statistical about this that you prefer it reside here? We can migrate this to math.SE for you.

Comment: Ok, Thank you, I will appreciate if you can migrate it to a more suitable place

Comment: I sure, can you found an example which the inequality does not hold?

Comment: what you wrote is a vector result, while the inequality above is scalar

Comment: 1 is scalar, its a row vector, then matrix and finally column vector, therefore produce a scalar

Comment: The matrix $$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ is non-negative definite but your expression equals $-2$.  Perhaps you would like to stipulate that $A$ also be symmetric?

Comment: tomer, if you want it moved somewhere, flag it for moderator attention and request it to be moved